# Associate all nameless file with notepad

Tags: windows, file-association

I've got lot of files that don't have a file name, begins with `.` and just have only an extension.

Is it possible to set a default program for all of them so I don't have to set it each-time

Answer (score 0):

Rather than specific associations, consider adding a program to the right-click menu of any file with the following.

> 1. Navigate to regedit.exe in the Start Menu—or hit Windows Key + R and type regedit.exe—and head to this key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT >
>      Directory > Background > shell
> 2. Right-click shell and select New > Key. Name the key the application you'd like to add to the context menu.
> 3. Now right-click the new key you just made and once again select New > Key. Name the key "command" in all lowercase.
> 4. In the new command key folder you just made, double-click the (Default) key located on the right-hand side of the window. In the
>      Value data section, put the path to the executable file for the
>      application you'd like to add to the context menu and hit OK.

http://lifehacker.com/add-any-application-to-the-windows-context-menu-1627589106

For more detailed instructions, visit the following page:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/